# Group concat not working when using in query for selecting multiple rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I have used the below query but not returning desired result.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `equipment_id`) FROM `cars` 
WHERE `car_id` IN (2,7);

table => cars

car_id      equipment_id 
2           1,3,4,6,7
7           1,4,6,7 

Returning => 1,3,4,6,7,1,3,4,7

It should return => 1,3,4,6,7
```

Thanks

Comment: i am asking about unique equipment_ids ?

Comment: Your values are stored as comma separated string and group_concat is not going to work the way you are expecting for those values.

Comment: so what should be the solution?

Comment: The solution is to normalize the data and dont store comma separated data. It should have entry for each `equipment_id` for a given `car_id`

Comment: Is there any other solution with mysql function??

Answer (score 0):

As Abhik pointed out, you should normalize your database schemas. Storing comma-separated values in a single attribute is not the way to go with an RDBMS.

Have a table with car_id, equipment_id with only 1 equipment_id per car_id. Let (car_id,equipment_id) constitute the primary key.